# How to use OpenMP to parallelize C++ using Visual studio

Tags: c++

I am trying to use OpenMP to parallelize C++ but I think I am missing something.

This is just a part of the original code.

```
omp_set_num_threads(8);
    // First loop
    #pragma omp parallel for 
    for (int a = 0; a < Na; a++) {
        for (int b = 0; b < Nd; b++) {
            for (int c = 0; c < Ny; c++) {
                max = -99999;
                for (int d = 0; d < Na; d++) {
                    for (int e = 0; e < Nd; e++) {
                        Val[d][e] = Uvec[a][b][c][d][e] + Vfuture[d][e];
                        if (max < Val[d][e]) {
                            max = Val[d][e];
                            maxposition_a[a][b][c] = d;
                            maxposition_d[a][b][c] = e;
                        }
                    }
                }
                Vnew[a][b][c] = max;
            }
        }
    }



    // Second loop
    #pragma omp parallel for 
    for (int h = 0; h < H; h++) {
        for (int i = 0; i < Na; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < Nd; j++) {
                for (int k = 0; k < Ny; k++) {
                    Vhoward[i][j][k] = Vnew[i][j][k];
                }
            }
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < Na; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < Nd; j++) {
                for (int k = 0; k < Ny; k++) {

                    temphoward[i][j] = beta * Vhoward[maxposition_a[i][j][k]][maxposition_d[i][j][k]][0] * Ptrans[0]
                        + beta * Vhoward[maxposition_a[i][j][k]][maxposition_d[i][j][k]][1] * Ptrans[1]
                        + beta * Vhoward[maxposition_a[i][j][k]][maxposition_d[i][j][k]][2] * Ptrans[2];
                    Vnew[i][j][k] = temphoward[i][j] + Uvec[i][j][k][maxposition_a[i][j][k]][maxposition_d[i][j][k]];
                }
            }
        }
    } 
}
```

So basically, I thought

1. omp_set_num_threads(8) to set the number of threads I am going to use.
2. Just add '#pragma omp parallel for' at the beginning of 'for' statements.

In this way, I could use 8 threads to do 'First loop' and after that, do 'Second loop' also with 8 threads.

However, it is slower than the one without '#pragma omp parallel for'. So I guess I am not using parallelization correctly.

How should I change this code?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: There are numerous problems. One test is the verify that the threaded version gives the same output as the single thread version. You have a lot of race conditions, with multiple threads writing to the same variables (e.g., `max`, `Vhoward`, `temphoward`). What is the `h` loop for? You never use `h` inside the loop body. If you're trying to refine the values in `Vnew`, you can't parallelize that with threads because the values used in the second loop depend on the output from the first loop.

Comment: h is just to repeat the loop 'H' times. Oh, you are right. I am just refining the values in Vnew so that it is impossible to parallelize 'Second loop'